# How to completely show long text of a button in React native?

Tags: css, react-native

I have a long text inside a button and i want to show it completely. I don’t know if `flexwrap` is the problem but i used it so i can center the text in the button. The problem is the text inside the button is being cut ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9i22.png)). I have my code like this :

```js
<TouchableOpacity
        style={[
          styles.container,
          customStyle
        ]}
        disabled={disabled}
        onPress={onPress}
        {...this.props}
>
        <Text
          style={[ styles.text ]}
        >
          { text }
        </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

```css
container: {
    height: 35,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    paddingHorizontal: 12,
    shadowOpacity: 0.20,
    shadowRadius: 4,
    paddingTop: 4,
    paddingBottom: 4,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: { height: 2, width: 0 },
    elevation: 2,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'white',
  },
  text: {
    fontFamily: 'calibril',
    textAlign: 'center',
    textTransform: 'uppercase',
    textAlignVertical: 'center',
  },
```

And i'm using my component like this:

```js
<Button
  theme="white"
  customStyle={[{ paddingHorizontal: 3, flexWrap: 'nowrap' }]}
  text={text}
  onPress={() => onPress()}
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change the style of the container

```
container: {
//height: 35,
  minHeight:35,
```

Comment: Thank you ! That was the answer for my problem

Comment: ok great, if this answer is valid for you please verify the answer

Comment: Firstly, this answer needs some more explanation why it works. Secondly, @shammi if this works then please mark it as the accepted answer.